# Connection timeout Feign Loadbalancer

Tags: netflix-eureka, hystrix, netflix-feign, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I have a FeignClient which is configured to connect to 2 different services via Eureka service discovery.
It works perfectly fine for Service A but throws a connection timeout exception for Service B. 
I can reach both the services manually and I can invoke the required end-points of both services manually as well.

Note:I have disabled the fallback to see the real error. Otherwise it always successfully exhibits the fallback behavior.

Here's the stacktrace

```
2018-05-09 06:31:01.955 ERROR 5668 --- [io-8082-exec-10] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is com.netflix.hystrix.exception.HystrixRuntimeException: ABCClient#getAllAplhabets() failed and no fallback available.] with root cause

java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:649) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:275) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:371) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1103) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:997) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1511) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1439) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at feign.Client$Default.convertResponse(Client.java:152) ~[feign-core-9.5.1.jar:na]
    at feign.Client$Default.execute(Client.java:74) ~[feign-core-9.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.ribbon.FeignLoadBalancer.execute(FeignLoadBalancer.java:89) ~[spring-cloud-openfeign-core-2.0.0.M2.jar:2.0.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.ribbon.FeignLoadBalancer.execute(FeignLoadBalancer.java:55) ~[spring-cloud-openfeign-core-2.0.0.M2.jar:2.0.0.M2]
    at com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient$1.call(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.java:104) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$3$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:303) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$3$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:287) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
    at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$3.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:231) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$3.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:228) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap$ConcatMapSubscriber.drain(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:286) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap$ConcatMapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:144) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:185) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:180) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap.call(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:94) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap.call(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:42) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10247) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10214) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.blockForSingle(BlockingObservable.java:444) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.single(BlockingObservable.java:341) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.executeWithLoadBalancer(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.java:112) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.ribbon.LoadBalancerFeignClient.execute(LoadBalancerFeignClient.java:63) ~[spring-cloud-openfeign-core-2.0.0.M2.jar:2.0.0.M2]
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:97) ~[feign-core-9.5.1.jar:na]
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:76) ~[feign-core-9.5.1.jar:na]
    at feign.hystrix.HystrixInvocationHandler$1.run(HystrixInvocationHandler.java:108) ~[feign-hystrix-9.5.1.jar:na]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:302) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar:1.5.12]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:298) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar:1.5.12]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:46) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:94) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContexSchedulerAction$1.call(HystrixContexSchedulerAction.java:56) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar:1.5.12]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContexSchedulerAction$1.call(HystrixContexSchedulerAction.java:47) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar:1.5.12]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContexSchedulerAction.call(HystrixContexSchedulerAction.java:69) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar:1.5.12]
    at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_20]
```

Comment: After some more debugging I found that the issue is occuring because its trying to connect to port 8080 and not 443 despite of following settings: `nonSecurePortEnabled: false
    securePortEnabled: true`

Comment: For service B, I had to add secure-port: 443 specifically in the application.yaml to make sure that it was always connecting to secure port. I had to do NO SUCH config in service A.